# Prove Stability of Iteration Matrix

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Given a positive definite Block-Matrix $H > 0$, where 
$$
H = \begin{pmatrix}H_{11} & H_{12} \\ H_{21} & H_{22} \end{pmatrix},
$$
where the iteration Matrix $A$ is given by
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -H_{11}^{-1}H_{12} \\ -H_{22}^{-1}H_{21} & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Show that the iteration matrix $A$ is stable, i.e. 
$$
|\text{eig}(A)|<1.
$$

I was thinking about the Gershgorin Circle theorem, but I'm not sure how that could be applied to a block matrix.
Any suggestions on what a good approach would be?